# Linq: Sort rows without first row

Tags: c#, linq

From below code I am getting sorted rows by first column. How to sort it by skipping first row

```
 var Rows = (from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
            orderby row[0] ascending                            
            select row);
```

**Note:** I want to sort rows by considering first column only. Please don't consider Name and City columns. (Say Name and City not present).

Original Table

```
ID             Name                     City
----------- --------------------------------
3             Vijendra                  Delhi
2             Singh                     Noida
1             Shakya                    New Delhi
5             Shakya                    New Delhi
4             Shakya                    New Delhi
```

Current O/P

```
ID             Name                     City
----------- --------------------------------
1             Shakya                    New Delhi
2             Singh                     Noida
3             Vijendra                  Delhi
4             Shakya                    New Delhi
5             Shakya                    New Delhi
```

EXpected O/P

```
ID             Name                     City
----------- --------------------------------
3             Vijendra                  Delhi
1             Shakya                    New Delhi
2             Singh                     Noida
4             Shakya                    New Delhi
5             Shakya                    New Delhi
```

Comment: What are the *actual* sorting rules here? Why are you specifically skipping the first record?

Comment: So based on your update, "*I want to sort rows by considering first column only. Please don't consider Name and City columns*" then what you have will do that, you need to be more specific as to why you want to skip the first record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something along this logic:

```
var firstId = ...
var Rows = (from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
            orderby row[0] == firstId descending, row[0] ascending                            
            select row);
```

Another option is to have an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderAfterFirst<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src,
                                                      Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    // Ensure you don't throw or return null or whatever if the collection is empty
    foreach (var first in src.Take(1))
    {
        yield return first;
    }

    // Return the rest of the elements ordered
    foreach (var x in src.Skip(1).OrderBy(keySelector))
    {
        yield return x;
    }
}
```

Then usage would be:

```
var rows = datatable.AsEnumerable().OrderAfterFirst(row => row[0]);
```

Comment: It's such a specific situation, I think an extension method is unnecessary. Maybe if it was more generic it would be better e.g. `SkipOrderBy(1, x => x)`.

Comment: @James Of course, as well as adding an order-direction parameter and supporting "then-by"... I was just giving a simple example.

Comment: yes but my point is your extension method as it stands doesn't really merit being an extension method because it's *very* specific to one particular scenario. Just my opinion.

Comment: @James My point is that my extension method is to be edited and generalized by whoever wants to do so, to the point where they are happy with it, on their own.

Comment: *Any* extension method can be generalized though, the problem is I think extension methods are misused....a lot, and I don't like seeing answers that suggest using one when it doesn't add any value. To put it another way, what advantages does an extension method give over just moving it into a reusable function? Remember, extension methods are against the *type*, not the data within therefore if it's not something that you would consider re-using on any other *types* of list then it's probably doesn't need to be an extension method.

Comment: I would never use this as an extension method if I didn't need it logically to be an actual extension of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. I relate to what you said about misusing extension methods, but I merely added another possible solution to my answer. If you want to teach the OP about when and when not to use extension methods, share a link.

Answer (score 3):

Should be pretty easy if you use List:

```
        var newList = new List<DataRow>(){originalList.First()};
        newList.AddRange(originalList.Where(x => x.row[0] != originalList.First().row[0]).OrderBy(x => x.row[0]));
```

Comment: this was along the lines of my initial answer (it's still in the edit box) but I refrained from posting because I thought if the OP could be more specific about their sorting rules they could probably get this in a single query.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need a `List` ? It can be easily done without `List` using `Concat`.

Comment: It can probably be done in 1000 ways. This is just one answer that's imo quite simple and elegant.

Comment: @KrzysztofZagrajek simple, yeah, elegant...not so sure. Sriram's answer is probably better as it's 100% LINQ.

Comment: What @James said and this will throw Exception when there is no elements in the table. Am not criticizing, Giving hint for people who are not aware of this.

Comment: It's good, but on the other hand - it enumerates original collection multiple times. That's one of the answers to "why List".

Comment: @KrzysztofZagrajek are you referring to Sriram's answer? Where in his answer is the list enumerated multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

You can order by a boolean, for example with the conditional operator:

```
var Rows = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
           let id = row.Field<int>(0)
           orderby id == 3 ? 0 : 1 ascending, id ascending                  
           select row;
```

this would also work, but i find the conditional operator more readable:

```
orderby id == 3 descending, id ascending
```

Even if it doesn't make much sense to me, if you want to stay the first row always on top, no matter what the content is, you could use `Object.ReferenceEquals`:

```
var Rows = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
   let id = row.Field<int>(0)
   let isFirstRow = ReferenceEquals(row, datatable.Rows[0])
   orderby isFirstRow descending, id ascending
   select row;
```

Comment: Above tables are just example, id value will be different

Comment: @Sam: then i have to repeat the question of James: "What are the actual sorting rules here? Why are you specifically skipping the first record? "

Comment: @Sam: however, i have edited my answer to provide a content-independent approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort everything except the first row and then merge it together with the first row:

```
var data = datatable.AsEnumerable();
var firstRow = data.Take(1);
var sorted = data.Skip(1).OrderBy(row=>row[0]);
var rows = firstRow.Concat(sorted);
```

or as one statement:

```
var rows = data.Take(1).Concat(data.Skip(1).OrderBy(row=>row[0]));
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use multiple order by conditions

```
var Rows = datatable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Name )
             .ThenByDescending(x => x.City )
             .ToList();
```

You can also use query syntax and say:

```
var Rows = (from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
       orderby row .Name , row.City descending
       select row ).ToList();
```